# Mutating closure does not compile if it's more complicated than one statement -- how to fix?

Tags: swift, parameters, closures

I'm using `AtomicBox` from Matt Gallagher's [CwlUtils](https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlUtils) in a small countdown:

```
class Countdown {
    private let counter: AtomicBox<Int>

    init(from start: Int) {
        self.counter = AtomicBox(start)
    }

    func countDown() {
        self.counter.mutate { $0 -= 1 }
    }
}
```

This works just fine. Now say I want to throw an error if the counter has already reached zero:

```
func countDown() throws {
    self.counter.mutate { 
        guard $0 > 0 else {
            throw MyError.alreadyZero
        }

        $0 -= 1
    }
}
```

Now `swift build` complains:

```
<unknown>:0: error: parameters may not have the 'var' specifier
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Applications/Xcode8.2/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/dhtp/Documents/CwlUtils/.build/debug.yaml
```

(Weird error message, by the way; they normally come nicer.)

What is going on here? Both versions mutate the internal value of `counter` (which is what gets passed to the paramete of `mutate`) in exactly the same way. Why is one legal and the other is not?

How can I declare the closure so that it compiles (and does what I want)?

I tried `{ (inout value) in ... }` but that gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure you are passing is declared to throw. The compiler can't infer the parameter to the closure is inout because it doesn't match the closure type that mutate expect.

If your guard performs an action that doesn't throw, it'll work as expected.

```
self.counter.mutate {
    guard $0 > 0 // Note the condition
    else { print("I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that") ; return }
    $0 -= 1
}
```

The error message is confusing. You should probably raise a bug at Swift.org.

Comment: My guess is the compiler somehow sees it as modifying the function being passed to `mutate`. kind of funky.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ A non throwing function is considered to be a specialisation of the throwing function with the same parameters i.e. `(inout Int) -> Void` is a subtype of  `(inout Int) throws -> Void`. So you can use a non throwing function where the parameter is declared as throwing, but you cannot use a throwing function where the parameter is not declared as throwing.

Answer (score 0):

We have to explicitly redeclare that the parameter is `inout` for some reason:

```
self.counter.mutate { (value: inout Int) in
    ...
}
```

will work as expected.

Well, in the concrete case we can not pass a throwing closure to `mutate`, but that is another issue.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is another issue. I think it's precisely because the closure he is passing is declared to throw. The compiler can't infer the parameter to the closure is inout because it doesn't match the closure type that mutate expects.

Comment: @JeremyP Ah, that makes sense. In that case, it's "only" the compiler message that's not being helpful. I've noticed a couple of times that we don't get messages "can't infer something useful because X" but instead "[I silently inferred myself into a dead end, and now] there is some error Y". :/